# Yii2 render view for console command

Tags: php, yii2

С помощью консоли я генерирую файл sitemap.xml, вся логика создания и генерации файла написана в контроллере. Как сделать шаблон файла sitemap(view) и потом просто в середину генерировать все?

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно добавить в контроллер формат ответа

```
public function actionTest()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_XML;

    return $this->renderPartial('test');
}
```

Если, что почитайте вот [это](http://dergeekblog.kerspe.com/?p=184) .